# Is this a valid proof that the sum of the angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I think I accidentally found a proof of the famous theorem that the sum of the angles of a triangle add up to $180 ^\circ$, but am not sure if it is correct. Here it is:
[image]

It can be proved that the median in a right triangle is equal to half the hypotenuse.
Consider an aritrary triangle $QRS$ , $ST\perp QR$ and finally let $U$ and $V$ be the midpoints of $QS,SR$ respectively. Then we know that $UQ=UT$,so $\angle UQT = \angle UTQ$ and for similar reasons $\angle UST = \angle UTS,\angle VST = \angle VTS$ and finally $\angle VTR = \angle VRT$. But $\angle UTQ +(\angle UTS+\angle VTS) + \angle VTR = 180^\circ=\angle UQT + (\angle UST + \angle VST) + \angle VRT = \angle UQT + \angle USV + \angle VRT$.

This is the proof that the median in a right triangle is equal to half the hypotenuse: First I will prove that the line connecting two midpoints is equal to half the opposite and is half of it.

From the diagram I hope you can see why $CTW\cong VWA$ and $VAZ\cong UBZ$ and $CT\| BU$ and $CT= BU$,so $CB = TU$ and $CB\| TU$. Using simple arithmetic you can see that $WZ = \frac{TU}{2}$.
[image]

Now on the the actual proof: let $F$ be the midpoint of the hypotenuse and let $FH\| GE$ By the parallel postulate (and the above result) we have that H is the midpoint of DG and therefore the perpendicular bisector from which it follows that $DF = FG$.[image]

Comment: Read more on the fifth postulate.

Comment: @Shailesh: You couldn't have been vaguer.

Comment: How you developed the thought that Ut=Uq im not gettin it

Comment: It can be proved that the median in a right triangle is equal to half the hypotenuse. And infact I posted a proof, check out the second and third diagrams

Comment: How do you know that $H$ is the midpoint of $DG$? And where are you using your results from the second diagram?

Comment: Thats exactly where I am using them. Consider this: We know that if H is the midpoint and we connect it to F the line segment is going to be parallel to EG (by the second diagram). But there is only one parallel line to EG from F (by the fifth postulate) so we know that since FH is by definition parallel to EG it passes trough the midpoint of DG. Is that clear?

Comment: @Alexander You know, you don't really need the second diagram. Actualy I believe you can't even really use is, since it relies on the triangle being acute (as far as I can see.) However, just start with the third one. You have $\angle FDH$ and the segments $DH$ and $DF$. This defines a unique triangle. And because $\vert DH\vert : \vert DF \vert= \vert DG\vert : \vert DE\vert$,  $\triangle DFH$ and $\triangle DEG$  are similar with scale $ 1:2$. The rest is obvious. Overall your proof is very nice.

Comment: Thanks. I hadnt thought of using similar triangles. Infact the proof involving the second diagram may also be proven using similarity . It doesnt require the triangle to be acute though, it works with all triangles. Furthermore the fact that the segment WZ is half the opposite is not important what is important is that it is parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct: it lies upon the theorem that the median in a right triangle is equal to half the hypotenuse, which in turn is a consequence of Euclid's Proposition 29 (if a transversal intersects two parallel lines, then the alternate interior angles are congruent) and of its corollaries.

But the theorem on the sum of the angles of a triangle is usually regarded as more fundamental than the theorem of the median in a right triangle, that's why a proof depending directly on Euclid's 29 is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a triangle ABC with vertex A at top and BC as base . Then draw a parallel line EAF to BC passing through A then see we have 2 pairs of alternate angles. Then $angle EAB=angleABC$ same for other side now note that $EAB+BAC+FAC=180..$ linear pair replace EAB with ABC and FAC with ACB see you have proven it. Hope its clear

Comment: But that is just the standard proof isnt it ? I am asking whether mine is correct.